# Selenium - scroll into view element within nested scrollbars

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to scroll an element into view before I can click it using the below selenium code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
```

But the issue is there are 2 vertical nested scroll bars. The first scroll bar is attached to the left side-bar. The second scroll bar is attached to the entire window.

When I run the above code only the first scroll bar is scrolled to the bottom, but the second scroll bar remains at the top.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser and version, you can tell `scrollIntoView` to scroll the element in the center of the view-port:

```javascript
arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});
```

If it doesn't work, you can still emulate the `scrollIntoView` by setting [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) and [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) on each scrollable container.

This example should scroll the targeted element to the center of the view:

```javascript
var elm = arguments[0],
  doc = elm.ownerDocument || document,
  getClientSize = function (max, a, b) {return Math.max(a <= max ? a : 0, b <= max ? b : 0) || max},
  clientWidth = getClientSize(doc.defaultView.innerWidth, doc.body.clientWidth, doc.documentElement.clientWidth),
  clientHeight = getClientSize(doc.defaultView.innerHeight, doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight),
  box = elm.getBoundingClientRect(),
  [x, y, w, h] = [box.left, box.top, box.width, box.height],
  clientX = Math.max(0, clientWidth - w) * 0.5,
  clientY = Math.max(0, clientHeight - h) * 0.5;

for (var e = elm; e; e = e.parentElement || e.offsetParent) {
  box = e.offsetParent ? e.getBoundingClientRect() : doc.head.getBoundingClientRect();
  x += e.scrollLeft;
  y += e.scrollTop;
  e.scrollLeft = x - box.left - Math.min(clientX, (e.clientWidth - w) * 0.5);
  e.scrollTop = y - box.top - Math.min(clientY, (e.clientHeight - h) * 0.5);
  x -= e.scrollLeft;
  y -= e.scrollTop;
}
```